# Mathematical function alike to primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, recurrence-relations

**Note: I'm currently in a low level algebra class and have very little knowledge of some of the more complex mathematical concepts. That being said, I can probably figure out anything I don't know through research.**

If I understand correctly, prime numbers become (roughly)exponentially less common and cannot be calculated readily with an explicit formula. Mainly what I'm interested is the fact that they become increasingly difficult to calculate and are more difficult to calculate than to verify(verifying 7 is prime is quicker than finding all prime numbers between 1 and 10). Is there another set of numbers like this, or are primes absolutely unique in this sense? I don't really care what the ratio is, as long as finding these numbers takes longer than it takes to verify them and cannot be found with an elementary function.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Are you asking for a set of numbers that have the same difficulty as the primes to find? Or just any set of numbers where the cost to verify grows at a much slower rate than the cost to find(how you find might need to be defined better since if you're using the successor function every exponential function has this characteristic).

Comment: I was looking for any set of numbers where the cost to verify grows much slower than the cost to find.

Comment: And what operations can you use to find? Just addition?

Comment: Any method to find it as long as new numbers cannot be found with a function.

Comment: Cannot be found with an elementary function. Every sequence of integers is representable as $f(n) : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Edited post for clarity.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean that primes are more difficult to verify than to calculate. Of course it is easier to verify that *one particular number* is prime than to find *all* primes in some range. E.g., it is quicker to check if $n$ is even than to list all even numbers between $1$ and $n$: the first one you can do in linear or in logarithmic time, depending on the representation of $n$; the second one needs at least linear time because you have to generate the output.

Comment: That's exactly what I mean, it's easier to verify 7 is prime than it is to find all primes between 1 and 10 and stumble upon 7.

Comment: All the numbers which are 1 more than a prime have the same property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Is there another set of numbers like this, or are primes absolutely unique in this sense?**

Primes are definitely not unique in this sense. For example, the sequence of [prime powers](http://oeis.org/A000961) (OEIS A000961) has all the same properties that you mentioned.

Another example is the sequence of [even perfect numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Even_perfect_numbers). Here the cost to verify is low because we know that each even perfect number $n$ must fit the formula $n=2^{p-1}(2^p-1)$ where both $p$ and $2^p-1$ are primes; see [Euclid-Euler theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid-Euler_theorem). On the other hand, the cost to find perfect numbers is very high. (We do not even know if there are infinitely many of them.)